# The value of X-max must be greater than the value of X-min

Tags: sql-server, geometry, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to create a spatial index for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeoResult](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,

    [PointCenter]  AS ([dbo].[ConvertToGeometryPoint]([LatitudeCenter],[LongitudeCenter])),

    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GeoResult] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to add a new spatial index using the Add Spatial Index wizard, I get this error:
[image: The value of X-max must be greater than the value of X-min.]

Given that my app needs to support worldwide locations, what should be the optimal values for the Bounding Box properties?

Comment: Assuming your 'world wide coordinates' are in units of decimal `lats + 'longs', then BOUNDING_BOX of (-180, -90, 180, 90) sounds reasonable?

Comment: May I ask what the data size implication of this setup is?

Comment: @Believe2014 The larger bounding box isn't going to increase the size of the data.  However if you're doing "world" scenarios then really you should be using Geography, not Geometry.

Comment: I know that the difference: geography = geometry + z coordinate. But is it true that the world scenario should always go with geography?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. You are using a geometry grid, but should use a geography grid.  Benchmark it yourself.
2. The documentation, at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, requires:

   > Bounding-box coordinates apply only within a USING GEOMETRY_GRID clause.
   >
   > xmax must be greater than xmin and ymax must be greater than ymin. You can specify any valid float value representation, assuming that: xmax > xmin and ymax > ymin. Otherwise the appropriate errors are raised.
   >
   > There are no default values.